# Ajax success function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've made a simple ajax/php form and my success function is not working properly for some reason. Im still getting emails, so i guess the condition is true, but the  is not appearing and the submit button is not blocked. Here's my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
          var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
          var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
          var company = document.getElementById("company").value;
          var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
          
        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
        var dataString = 'name1=' + name + '&message1=' + message + '&company1=' + company + '&phone1=' + phone;
          if (name == '' || message == '' || company == '' || phone == '') {
             document.getElementById("error").style="display: block; color: red;";
        } else {
          
          
        // AJAX code to submit form.
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "email.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
              document.getElementById("success").style="display: block; color: green;";
            }
          });
        }
        return false;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  
    <head>
    
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      
      <title>AJAX + PHP форма</title>
      
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      
      <style type="text/css">
        
        .input_group {
          
          display:inline-block;
          padding: 5px;
          width:100%;
          text-align: center;
          
        }
        
        form {
          
          width: 50%;
          
        }
        
        #send_message {
          text-align: center;
        }
        
      </style>
        
      
    </head>
    
    <body>
      
      <form id="contact" action="">
        
        <fieldset>
          
          <legend>AJAX + PHP форма</legend>
          
            <div class = "input_group">
        
              <label for="name" id="name_label">Имя</label> <br/>

              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="50" value="" class="text-input" required = "required"/>
              
            </div>
          
            <br/>
          
            <div class = "input_group">

              <label for="company" id="company_label">Компания</label> <br/>

              <input type="text" name="company" id="company" size="50" value="" class="text-input" required = "required" />
              
            </div>
              
            <br/>
          
            <div class = "input_group">
              
              <label for="phone" id="phone_label">Телефон</label> <br/>

              <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="50" value="" class="text-input" required = "required" />
              
            </div>
          
            <br/>
              
            <div class = "input_group">
              
              <label for="msg_text" id="msg_label">Запрос</label> <br/>

              <textarea rows="6" cols="51" name="question" id="message" required = "required"></textarea>
            
            </div>
          
            <div class = "input_group">
        
              <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" id="submit" value="Отправить" />
              
            </div>
            
          </fieldset>
        
      </form>
      
      <h2 style="display:none;" id ="error">Заполните все поля!</h2>
      <h2 style="display:none;" id="success">Message sent!</h2>
```

1. List item

Comment: are you certain that the "success" function is firing? Check your console and network tab for errors, and check the HTTP status code returned by the ajax call. If it's not 200, then "success" will not run - instead you should handle the "error" callback as well - see the ajax docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Yea i've checked it, im getting 200. And getting emails inbox as well.

Comment: p.s. you know instead of building your datastring by hand (which could be error-prone), you can save yourself the headache by just doing `$("#contact").serialize();`

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the style attribute as a string with `el.style`. Either set each style individually (.style.display,. style.color,...) or use

```
$('#success').css({display: 'block', color: 'green'})
```

Comment: I agree that this is not a right way of doing it..even I was surprised to see this working!!! not sure whether all browsers will support this :)

Comment: Actually i've tried just to alert on success - it still is not working. The live form is on http://www.learning.for-test-only.ru

Comment: Looks like the entire function is not working for some reason... :(

Comment: @atogz just tried your form on  learning.for-test-only.ru and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

this is your final code which working fine for me

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>AJAX + PHP форма</title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">

    .input_group {

      display:inline-block;
      padding: 5px;
      width:100%;
      text-align: center;

    }

    form {

      width: 50%;

    }

    #send_message {
      text-align: center;
    }

  </style>


</head>

<body>

  <form id="contact" action="">

    <fieldset>

      <legend>AJAX + PHP форма</legend>

        <div class = "input_group">

          <label for="name" id="name_label">Имя</label> <br/>

          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="50" value="" class="text-input" required = "required"/>

        </div>

        <br/>

        <div class = "input_group">

          <label for="company" id="company_label">Компания</label> <br/>

          <input type="text" name="company" id="company" size="50" value="" class="text-input" required = "required" />

        </div>

        <br/>

        <div class = "input_group">

          <label for="phone" id="phone_label">Телефон</label> <br/>

          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="50" value="" class="text-input" required = "required" />

        </div>

        <br/>

        <div class = "input_group">

          <label for="msg_text" id="msg_label">Запрос</label> <br/>

          <textarea rows="6" cols="51" name="question" id="message" required = "required"></textarea>

        </div>

        <div class = "input_group">

          <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" id="submit" value="Отправить" />

        </div>

      </fieldset>

  </form>

  <h2 style="display:none;" id ="error">Заполните все поля!</h2>
  <h2 style="display:none;" id="success">Message sent!</h2>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
      var company = document.getElementById("company").value;
      var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;

    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    var dataString = 'name1=' + name + '&message1=' + message + '&company1=' + company + '&phone1=' + phone;
      if (name == '' || message == '' || company == '' || phone == '') {
         document.getElementById("error").style="display: block; color: red;";
    } else {

    // AJAX code to submit form.
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "demo.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
          $('#success').css({display: 'block', color: 'green'});
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

and this is demo php file

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
 ?>
```

just update button type submit to button

Comment: i have faced this problem few year ago but i saw it is working now. so sorry

Comment: I agree that this is not a right way of doing it..I was surprised to see this working!!! not sure whether all browsers will support this :)

Comment: That solution also doesnt work for me. I even tried to simply alert, instead of accessing DOM - still no result. The live form can be seen there: http://www.learning.for-test-only.ru

Comment: i saw there is no data in send in console so please set demo data for test or alert dataString before ajax. for test 

data: "email=email_test", set this

Comment: just wait a minutes, i am checking it

Comment: Alerting dataString before ajax now. Alert is working, the string looks fine. Getting emails.

Comment: Brilliant, with input type = "button" it's working now! Why's that happening though, why is submit not good enough? I want to understand that solution and would appreciate if you explain.

Comment: when you button type submit then form will be submit and no ajax effect , but when you set type button then ajax effect will occur and you can also submit this form using ajax , if this is work then give me vote . ha ha ha